# Combining For Loop in Python

Tags: python

suppose message = 1 and contact A in the file and I want to print

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D

for message in peoplename:
    for contact in contacts_list:
        time.sleep(10)
        print (message, contact)
```

but it printing like this

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
1 D
2 A
2 B
2 C
2 D
3 A
3 B
3 C
3 D
4 A
4 B
4 C
4 D
```

please let me know how to fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to match the first item in `peoplename` with the first item in `contacts_list`, second with the second etc. You do that using function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for message, contact in zip(peoplename, contacts_list):
    time.sleep(10)
    print (message, contact)
```

Comment: not working as well using Zip or iter tools

Comment: @user3416720 In that case, provide enough information for us to be able to reproduce. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `zip`:

```
message = [1,2,3,4]
people = ['A','B','C','D']
for x,y in zip(message,people):
  print(x,y)
#Prints
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

You can run [Live](https://repl.it/@johirbuet/PunctualGiantYottabyte)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the lists' length instead.

```
length = len(peoplename)
if legnth != len(contacts_list):
    raise ValueError("Lists have different lengths")

for i in range(length):
    time.sleep(10)
    print (peoplename[i], contact_list[i])
```

Comment: That does the same thing as `zip`, but uglier...

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ What? How could it be more readable to reimplement zip in every place where you need it, instead of using the built-in function which everyone who ever used python understands?!